# Xubuntu 14.04: task bar icon for google chrome is gone?

Tags: xubuntu, google-chrome, icons

I think since the lastest google chrome update (today), the icon used in the task bar looks like this:

[image: dumb icon screenshot]

but at least in the launcher, it still looks "ok":

[image: launcher screen shot]

When I check the launcher properties (for the icon displayed there, also all good).

Any idea?

Comment: I don't think this is an Ubuntu glitch. I'm pretty sure this is something with Chrome, be it a bug or some new feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in Chrome / Chromium, see this related reports:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=478714
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1449063

It was fixed in Chrome 43.0.2357.81.